# Can Apache FOP 0.95 render Emoticons?

Tags: java, utf-8, apache-fop

We are using Apache FOP 0.95 rendering system and the rendering engine crashes when it encounters a UTF-8 emoticon. I am using Java to render the data to PS/PDF format.

Is there a way to render them correctly or filter these non-renderable characters?

Here is the exception:
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.FuncDocument.warn(FuncDocument.java:419)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.FuncDocument.getDoc(FuncDocument.java:356)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.FuncDocument.execute(FuncDocument.java:192)
    at org.apache.xpath.Expression.bool(Expression.java:184)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.bool(XPath.java:410)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemChoose.execute(ElemChoose.java:124)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformToRTF(TransformerImpl.java:1999)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformToGlobalRTF(TransformerImpl.java:1944)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemVariable.getValue(ElemVariable.java:308)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.XUnresolvedVariable.execute(XUnresolvedVariable.java:124)
    at org.apache.xpath.VariableStack.getGlobalVariable(VariableStack.java:446)
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.execute(Variable.java:212)
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.execute(Variable.java:186)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.FuncDocument.execute(FuncDocument.java:77)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemVariable.getValue(ElemVariable.java:278)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.XUnresolvedVariable.execute(XUnresolvedVariable.java:124)
    at org.apache.xpath.VariableStack.getGlobalVariable(VariableStack.java:446)
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.execute(Variable.java:212)
    at org.apache.xpath.operations.Variable.execute(Variable.java:186)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.WalkingIterator.setRoot(WalkingIterator.java:154)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.NodeSequence.setRoot(NodeSequence.java:213)
    at org.apache.xpath.axes.LocPathIterator.execute(LocPathIterator.java:210)
    at org.apache.xpath.XPath.execute(XPath.java:335)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemVariable.getValue(ElemVariable.java:278)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemVariable.execute(ElemVariable.java:246)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:392)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:246)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1374)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:392)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:246)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1374)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1374)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:392)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:246)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1374)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemTemplate.execute(ElemTemplate.java:392)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemCallTemplate.execute(ElemCallTemplate.java:246)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemIf.execute(ElemIf.java:160)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemApplyTemplates.transformSelectedNodes(ElemApplyTemplates.java:393)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemApplyTemplates.execute(ElemApplyTemplates.java:176)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemLiteralResult.execute(ElemLiteralResult.java:1374)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemApplyTemplates.transformSelectedNodes(ElemApplyTemplates.java:393)
    at org.apache.xalan.templates.ElemApplyTemplates.execute(ElemApplyTemplates.java:176)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.executeChildTemplates(TransformerImpl.java:2411)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.applyTemplateToNode(TransformerImpl.java:2281)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transformNode(TransformerImpl.java:1367)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:709)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1284)
    at org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl.transform(TransformerImpl.java:1262)

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: Yes. I want to get rid of these system specific characters. How do I do that?

Comment: Edit your post and include the question.

Comment: U+2B50 is ⭐ (WHITE MEDIUM STAR). What's system specific about that?

Comment: It renders as a star on apple computers. When I try to render it using Apache FOP, it crashes.

Comment: It also renders as a star on my Windows laptop and my Linux box.

Comment: If you give us the actual error that you are encountering, we may be able to help you fix the issue, rather than suggest broad, hackish workarounds. That character is definitely renderable. What is the error that is thrown?

Answer (score 1):

You don't say what the unwanted characters are in ...

The `String.replaceAll()` method is a good way to get rid of unwanted characters ... in a String.

But the other problem is knowing what these unrenderable characters are. And besides, these characters are defined by the Unicode standard ... they are not system specific in meaning.

---

I think you would be better off figuring out *why* FOP is crashing, and fixing the cause of that crash.  There is no obvious reason why FOP shouldn't be able to cope with any printable character.  My guess is that it is something to do with the way you are using FOP ...

Comment: I have more examples of these characters: ✨, , <U+2757>
I do not have an exhaustive list of those that cannot be rendered. I produce a PS/PDF file as an output from the Apache renderer.

Comment: The characters in question are *not* system-specific, and deleting them is unlikely to be the best solution. Can you update your question to provide more information about the crash (exact error message, if any)?